# Does Unity work on Intel GMA x4500?

Tags: unity, intel-graphics

Does anyone use Unity with an Intel GMA x4500 graphic card? Does it work?

Comment: Apparently, no. See [ubuntu problem with dual monitor reset][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126455/ubuntu-12-04-dual-monitor-reset-bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to be more confident on this than evgeny:

**It works marvellously!**

In fact, the Intel graphics have the *best drivers of them all*. Sure, the performance isn't comparable to an NVidia 250 series or something, but it's more than enough for unity. If there is something wrong, you can be pretty much sure it doesn't have to do with your Intel X4500.

(This applies to all Intel graphics chipsets apart from the GMA500 aka. Poulsbo)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I hope it'll be the best. I need it mostly for development and daily usage, no extreme gaming and 3d stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Short question, short answer: YES

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition on a Belinea o.book 13011 with Intel GMA4500HD and it works fine. I dont have the performace issue many Netbook user are reporting

Answer (score 1):

I see you already have an answer, but I see that there are disagreements between users that this card is not supported. Here is proof that I have for some users that the card does work.

[image]

But, this is not proof that it WILL work in every istance. This proves that it CAN work more than anything. I myself had no issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for me. I'm certainly not savvy enough to perform any troubleshooting but I'm just giving my out of the box experience. The whole desktop is struggling and sometimes I even loose the "unity theming" leaving me with e.g. nautilus windows looking like Windows 3.11.
forum topic: 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11415361

Ubuntu 11.10 x64, Lenovo Thinkpad T500

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use Ubuntu 12.04, then no it does not work as of this writing. You'll need to use 2D mode only.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide a source or explanation for this (for example, by linking to other sources)?