# Is this a dual monitor reset bug?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

My two displays are:

- Intel GMA x4500 Laptop (1280x800 native resolution of the built-in display)
- External display (1920x1080)

A few minutes after I login to my dual monitor setup, it gets reset to mirror screens. If I restore the settings via the displays application, everything is fine.
On each reset, the following messages are written into `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`:

```
[    60.852] (II) PM Event received: Capability Changed
[    60.852] I830PMEvent: Capability change
[   132.920] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12869
[   132.920] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   132.920] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   68.94  1280 1296 1344 1408  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (49.0 kHz)
[   134.228] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 1280x800 stride 5120, tiled
```

Whereas right on startup or manual resolution reset, `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` reports the expected frame buffer allocation:

```
[  1562.382] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "SEC", prod id 12869
[  1562.382] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  1562.382] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1280x800"x0.0   68.94  1280 1296 1344 1408  800 801 804 816 -hsync -vsync (49.0 kHz)
[  1576.740] (II) intel(0): Allocated new frame buffer 3200x1080 stride 12800, tiled
```

Is Ubuntu 12.04 not compatible with my video card?

Can this be solved within Ubuntu?

I like its interface, but manually fiddling with resolution on every login is not bearable.

Answer (score 0):

I am using intel xorg driver and can't get dual monitors (laptop + monitor) working. It worked fine in 11.10.

You could try deleting `~/.config/monitors.xml` which didn't work for me although it did get my displays to mirror.

But maybe something went wrong in the upgrade. It may be worth backing up everything and doing a clean install of 12.04?

Comment: This **was** a clean install. I've noticed that this "PM capability change" also happens with just one monitor causing short flickering. But again, after flickering everything is fine. These two lines seem to indicate the cause (intel video driver):

[    60.852] (II) PM Event received: Capability Changed

[    60.852] I830PMEvent: Capability change

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem with Intel GM45 drivers.
Everything seemed to be fine after logging in, but as soon as I pressed the "super/windows key" or starting any application, the screen changed to "mirror" mode.
Setting it in the system settings or using xrandr to my desired setup made everything fine.
It seems that after log in, the capabilities of the graphics card/monitor change. I don't know exactly the cause, but it might have something to do with the "samsung tools" I use. Anyway, letting the script

```
sleep 10
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --primary
xrandr --output VGA1 --auto --above LVDS1
```

run on startup made everything fine